# How can i create input text fields dynamically in react js - JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to reactjs, i came across a scenario where i've to create 6 input fields which are very much similar to each other. Right now i've something like this in my render method of class,

```
render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>
                <label htmlFor="answer1">Answer:</label><br/>
                <input
                type="text"
                name="answer1"
                id="answer1"
                className="answer"
                value={this.state.answer1}
                onChange={this._handleChange}
                />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input
                type="text"
                name="answer2"
                id="answer2"
                className="answer"
                value={this.state.answer2}
                onChange={this._handleChange}
                />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input
                type="text"
                name="answer3"
                id="answer3"
                className="answer"
                value={this.state.answer3}
                onChange={this._handleChange}
                />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input
                type="text"
                name="answer4"
                id="answer4"
                className="answer"
                value={this.state.answer4}
                onChange={this._handleChange}
                />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input
                type="text"
                name="answer5"
                id="answer5"
                className="answer"
                value={this.state.answer5}
                onChange={this._handleChange}
                />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input
                type="text"
                name="answer6"
                id="answer6"
                className="answer"
                value={this.state.answer6}
                onChange={this._handleChange}
                />
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The code is ugly and redundant, is there anyway i could do this dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about defining an `Answer` component like this (only showing the render method):

```
render() {
  return (
    <p>
        <label htmlFor={this.props.name}>Answer:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name={this.props.name}
          className="answer"
          value={this.props.value}
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}
        />
    </p>  
  );
}
```

And then on your parent component you just import it and use it like:

```
var Answer = require('./answer.js');
//..

render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Answer name="answer1" value={this.state.answer1} handleChange={this._handleChange} />
          <Answer name="answer2" value={this.state.answer2} handleChange={this._handleChange} />
          <Answer name="answer3" value={this.state.answer3} handleChange={this._handleChange} />
          // add all your Answer components
        </div>                    
    );
}
```

Following Thylossus suggestion, here is an example using `map`:

```
var Answer = require('./answer.js');
//...

render() {
  // this is supposing you've got an answers array of { name: ..., value: ...} object
  var answers = this.state.answers.map(function(a) {
    return(<Answer name={a.name} value={a.value} handleChange={this._handleChange} />)
  });
  return (
    <div>
      { answers }
    </div>                    
  );
}
```

Comment: This could be further developed by using the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create the list of Answer components dynamically as in https://thinkster.io/iterating-and-rendering-loops-in-react. In this case, however, the `key` property has to be set as explained in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children)

Comment: @Thylossus I agree (and will add a short example using `map`) though it isn't clear from the sample what one could map on.

Comment: You have `this.state.answers()` -- you mean `this.state.answers.map()`. It's personal preference, but I would just inline it in the JSX instead of assigning it to a variable and then interpolating that in the JSX. Also personal preference / depends on the situation, but `Answer` could just be defined in the same file, and could be a stateless functional component if it makes sense (essentially a helper function to return a `ReactElement`).

Comment: @JMM yes, `Answer` could totally be a stateless functional component. Not sure it comes easy to a react beginner though.

Comment: @mfirry you're absolutely right. I just wanted to mention the option for reference. Thank you for including the example in your answer!

Comment: If I m not wrong when you are looping like use of 'map' above, u need also a key for each component, a requirement by React.